# How to get Emmet recognize text replacement or aliases in class names?

Tags: html, sublimetext, emmet

For example: ".row>.small-9-centered.small-3-centered" by writing " from writting ".row>div.s9c.s3c". I am trying to tell emmet to replace "s9c" for "small-9-centered".

Any suggestions? If it is not possible, any way you know to script a plugin to do this by detecting the next of . "dot" and before another dot or >.

I was looking for a text replacement, or something like var replacement in sublime but I did find anything, even if I would, maybe It wouldn't be recognized by the Emmet parser, that is why I was looking something like Snippets abbreviations but only for text, since emmet snippets always assumes it is a tag and adds closing tags.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using this line of javascript `str.replace("s9c", "small-9-centered");`, it is looking for a string and replacing it with another. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JchE5/448/

javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("change").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("s9c", "small-9-centered");
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: This does not work since Emmet is a template syntax for generating HTML, Emmet won't render the result of the JS parsing you are proposing.